# "FLASK_ENV is deprecated..." what is the alternative to FLASK_ENV=production?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I just found out that `FLASK_ENV` is deprecated. And although I found the solution to setting `DEBUG` mode as `FLASK_DEBUG=True`, when I go back to try testing error handling (with debug mode turned off), I couldn't work out how to get the mode set to production as it used to be -> `FLASK_ENV=production`.

I tried `YOURAPPLICATION_MODE='Production'` but it returned the following:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

I tried [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#development-production) but couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned `FLASK_DEBUG=True` is the [new way](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#DEBUG) to indicate debug level, however for your main question, the thing is the `flask run` server IS only for development.

For production you should use some proper server, e.g. uvicorn, gunicorn or as [Flask suggests](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/deploy/), Waitress.

With that configuration you don't need to set any flag/environment variable.

You can still use `flask run` for developing.